# Trying to detect ActionMode memory leak

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to find the source of ActionMode memory leak for days now without luck. I have an activity with several fragments and when I leave the fragment having ActionMode (while auto cancelling it), LeakCanary detects a memory leak.

I have nulled both ActionMode and ActionMode.Callback on destroy() and even tried doing it on onDestroyActionMode().

Here is my LeakCanary screenshot:

https://i.imgur.com/RUbdqj3.png

I hope someone points me in the right direction.

P.S. I have suspected it has something to do with ActionMode.Callback. Though, I could not find any methods for the CallBack that destroys it. I start the ActionMode using startSupportActionMode(mActionModeCallback). I have tried to find a method to remove the mActionModeCallback from that, too, but no methods.

Here is my full ActionMode code:

```
private ActionMode mActionMode;
private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback;

public void startCAB()
{
    if (mActionMode == null)
        mActionMode = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).startSupportActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
}


private void buildActionModeCallBack()
{
    mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_cab, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                ... Some Code ...
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            mActionMode = null;
    mActionModeCallback = null; // Tried with and without this.
        }
    };
}

public void finishActionMode()
{
    mActionMode.finish();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    mActionMode = null;
    mActionModeCallback = null;
}
```

Parent Activity containing fragments:

```
@Override
public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
{
    clearCAB();
}

private void clearCAB()
{
    int index = mPagerAdapter.getCurrentFragmentIndex();
    FragmentOne fragmentOne = (FragmentOne) mPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(mViewPager, index);
    fragmentOne.finishActionMode();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `mActionMode.finish()` instead of setting the reference explicitly to `null`?

Comment: Yes, I have added the code from my parent activity, that shows where I finish the CAB on swipe.

Comment: Hitting the same issue in my app, which uses a listview inside a fragment, hosted in a view pager.

Comment: Without seeing this question I was looking at the source code because it seemed suspicious I couldn't unset the `ActionMode.Callback`. Once you call `AppCompatActivity.startSupportActionMode(mActionModeCallback)` the `ActionMode.Callback` is never dereferenced once you call `ActionMode.finish` hence the callback always has a strong reference. A solution is to make a callback concrete implementation that has the same lifecycle as the Application, and then set / unset variables in the custom callback implementation yourself, that way the who fragment is not leaked - this is a aosp bug.

Comment: over a year and a half after this post, i have exactly the problem. did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 4):

According to my experience, if your `ActionMode.Callback` object use the **Anonymous inner class** it may cause your fragment memory leak.

Maybe you can create a new class and implements `ActionMode.Callback` then use it to put in `startSupportActionMode()` parameter:

```
public class YourFragment extends skip implements skip, ActionMode.Callback {

    private ActionMode mActionMode;

    public void startCAB()
    {
        if (mActionMode == null)
            mActionMode = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).startSupportActionMode(new SafeActionModeCallback(this));
    }

    public void finishActionMode()
    {
        mActionMode.finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_cab, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // ... Some Code ...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        mActionMode = null;
    }
}
```

SafeActionModeCallback:

```
public class SafeActionModeCallback implements ActionMode.Callback {

    // you can also use the WeakReference
    private ActionMode.Callback callback;

    public SafeActionModeCallback(ActionMode.Callback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return callback.onCreateActionMode(mode, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return callback.onPrepareActionMode(mode, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        return callback.onActionItemClicked(mode, item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        callback.onDestroyActionMode(mode);
        callback = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried something similar where instead of having a ActionMode.Callback variable i used lambdas (kotlin) and this did not work - fragment still leaks

Comment: Definitely works for me, the leak is gone.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the ActionMode in the activity has a reference to the fragment's layout  which is causing the memory leak and preventing the fragment from getting GC'ed.  I couldn't find a way to remove the reference.

In my use case, I'm using a ListView inside the fragment that was activating the activity's ActionMode (via listener.setMultiChoiceModeListener).

My hacky solution: In the fragment's onDestroyView, remove the listView (or whichever view activated the ActionMode) from the layout and remove all listeners for the list view. I made a kotlin extension method for it:

```
fun ListView.removeViewAndClearListeners() {
    setMultiChoiceModeListener(null)
    setOnScrollListener(null)
    onItemClickListener = null

    (parent as? ViewGroup)?.removeView(this)
}
```

After doing this, the leak is gone.

Comment: Sorry, for the late reply since I did not notice the comments. What do you mean by activated exactly?

Comment: Activated means that the action mode is 'active' and showing the context buttons in the menu

Comment: Ok, how do I find the view that did that exactly? What is the line of code that I should check for?

Comment: For me it’s obvious because I attach the action mode to a list view. If you don’t know, maybe you can find it programmatically or attaching a breakpoint.

Comment: What is the line you use to attach it exactly? Thanks for the help.

Comment: listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(...)

Comment: @milu, I apologize for the late reply. Sadly, a listview is different from a RecyclerView. With a listview you use something like setMultiChoiceModeListener(). RecyclerView does not have anything similar. You can start the ActionMode directly. I simply pass a call from the adapter to the fragment which starts the ActionMode. Thank you so much for taking the time to try and help me, though. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you inspect the view hierarchy to see what the action mode is attached to? Maybe attach a breakpoint and navigate the tree?

Answer (score -1):

I am still wondering why you are relying on ActionMode.Callback. I had an application where I was supposed to create a Custom Menu on long press and I wasted almost 2 months on this issue :

[ActionModeCallback does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46339084/actionmodecallback-does-not-work)

I am not sure If you are aware of this or not, The ActionMode Callback barely works on all devices. After a lot of research, I came to know that devices who are focusing too much on battery consumption and optimization will not let your background services and some callbacks work as expected.

Try testing your code on MI or Oppo/Vivo devices. It will jump directly to **onDestroyActionMode** instead of calling **onActionItemClicked**